# Texmaker crashes as soon as I open an "environment" \begin{}

Tags: texmaker, bugs

I have reinstalled Windows 10 and I'm now having trouble with the last version of Texmaker (5.0.2).

I'm working on quite a long .tex file (300 pages) and Texmaker crashes as soon as I write `\begin{` or even just `{`. I have no log, I just get "Texmaker does not work anymore, the program cannot be correctly executed..." (translation) and I can just click "break" and it closes.

However I can copy a whole paragraph containing `\begin{...} ... \end{...}`, start a new section and even compile the whole suff. Texmaker also works on minimal files with the same preamble.

I guess it has to do with the size of the file, but it used to work fine with the previous version (already on Windows 10).

---

I have just learned about a "Windows application log" and here is what I get:
(neither german nor english is my mother tongue)

> Name der fehlerhaften Anwendung: texmaker.exe, Version: 0.0.0.0, Zeitstempel: 0x59904495

Name of failung application ... Time stamp

> Name des fehlerhaften Moduls: texmaker.exe, Version: 0.0.0.0, Zeitstempel: 0x59904495
>
> Ausnahmecode: 0xc00000fd

Exception code

> Fehleroffset: 0x00000000000bbd33

Error offset?

> ID des fehlerhaften Prozesses: 0x838

ID of the failing process

> Startzeit der fehlerhaften Anwendung: 0x01d3a6a3d261eddc

Begin time

> Pfad der fehlerhaften Anwendung: C:\Program Files (x86)\Texmaker\texmaker.exe

Path

> Pfad des fehlerhaften Moduls: C:\Program Files (x86)\Texmaker\texmaker.exe
>
> Berichtskennung: a8158e25-7cb8-42af-ad3c-dc7a686a3d64

Report identification

> Vollständiger Name des fehlerhaften Pakets:
>
> Anwendungs-ID, die relativ zum fehlerhaften Paket ist:
>
> System
>
> - Provider
>
>   [ Name]  Application Error
> - EventID 1000
>
>   [ Qualifiers]  0
>
>   Level 2
>
>   Task 100
>
>   Keywords 0x80000000000000
> - TimeCreated
>
>   [ SystemTime]  2018-02-15T21:32:08.705388000Z
>
>   EventRecordID 1589
>
>   Channel Application
>
>   - EventData
>
>   texmaker.exe
>
>   0.0.0.0
>
>   59904495
>
>   texmaker.exe
>
>   0.0.0.0
>
>   59904495
>
>   c00000fd
>
>   00000000000bbd33
>
>   838
>
>   01d3a6a3d261eddc
>
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Texmaker\texmaker.exe
>
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Texmaker\texmaker.exe
>
>   a8158e25-7cb8-42af-ad3c-dc7a686a3d64

Comment: Does Texmaker have an auto-compile mode? If so, is it enabled? if so, does disabling it help? Can you write `\begin{` in a hello, world! document? Or can you only write text, even there? Whatever the equivalent of a user account is on Windows, make a new one and see if the problem is reproducible there. If so, try deleting or disabling any files which contain preference settings relevant to Texmaker. (I guess Windows has this kind of thing?) Try a different editor. Does that handle the problem OK?

Comment: @cfr I don't think Texmaker compiles the file unless I strike F1. It does work when I create a new file without anything. I had just reinstalled Windows without any other sofware. I don't think there were any preferences left.