# Texmaker crashes when typing \begin{

Tags: texmaker, bugs

I have a .tex document with 9021 lines. I use Texmaker 5.1.3 on Windows 10. I have uninstalled and reinstalled.

All of a sudden today when I start typing `\begin` as soon as I type `{` Texmaker just crashed. There is no error message or anything.

I think my problem is similar to

[Texmaker crashes as soon as I open an "environment" \begin{}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415467/texmaker-crashes-as-soon-as-i-open-an-environment-begin)

This only seems to happen with my long document.

Comment: This was raised as in issue last year, not sure if it is relevant to your issues but there are similarities and a possible solution here: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=34544

Comment: @JamesTL Thank you I will take a look at that.

Comment: @JamesT unfortunately I also found that link but rather than a solution, they suggest to install TexStudio. This same issue is now happening to me, the Change Log of TexMaker does not seem to include any fix to this problem yet unfortunately...